# How to get visible-only sum of items that have been auto-filtered with a criteria?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have been using `=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(I2,ROW(I2:I61)-ROW(I2),0)),(B2:B61=B91)+0)` in excel to get the sum but only if the row is visible and where a criteria in another cell matches and it worked fine but when i use it in [google](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v2cUElA1iarh1Wm6Vyj54SyvKkG81UlaNYR50gv9JuA/edit?usp=sharing) sheets i get an `mismatched range size` error.

What did i do wrong or rather how can i get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there's more powerful [`filter`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) function that gives you an option to filter data on the fly:

`=sum(FILTER(I2:I61,N2:N61="00:01:00",B2:B61="Amazon Elastic Transcoder",M2:M61="1080p"))`

Comment: But with that function the result won't change if a change one of the autofilter

Comment: Yes, but if you change "00:01:00", "Amazon Elastic Transcoder", "1080p" to cell refferences, it may be even faster then changing filter. Try function `FILTER(I2:I61,N2:N61="00:01:00",B2:B61="Amazon Elastic Transcoder",M2:M61="1080p")` and see the result of filter in place

Answer (score 2):

It appears that, in Google Sheets, `SUBTOTAL` does not behave precisely as it does in Excel.

There are intimations as to a workaround here:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/6pSkI33ylHM

Regards